# Simpletip position in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, tooltip

I am using a [Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) plugin on my web page.

In IE and Chrome the layout of the tooltip in the container is correct. But in Firefox, I get a "cut-off" at the container's edge:

[image: tooltip cut-off]

A markup and the tooltips style is available on firebug snapshot (if you ctrl+scrollUp it is "see-able"):

[image: firebug snap]

How can I get the tooltip to be "over container" even in FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `overflow` css setting. The conteinver of the simpletip was set to `overflow-y:auto`, which allows scroll to appear if elements "want" to go below the visible area of the container, but everything that goes "to the left" of it is concatinated, and there is no combination of `overflow-x: visible` or something to set it "straight" at the moment. Had to programmatically compute the position of the tip and force it to appear to the right on the edge elements.